# Can't render an HTML within a Rails 3 view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I'm trying to display an html file that is uploaded with Carrierwave with:

```
<%= render :file => "#{@result.result_url}"  %>
```

But I get Missing template /results/100602f010.htm

I've tried :template => false, but that doesn't work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`render :file => "foo"` expects an absolute path by default, so unless you really have a root directory in your file system called `/results` your path is incomplete.

Comment: It's under my public folder. It wouldn't check there? public/results/[file]

EDIT: Apparently not. Had to add "public" to it. Thanks!